# Resolve css link Thymeleaf external project

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am making a small framework for sending emails to be used in the community. In this framework there is the possibility of sending pre-defined emails. To resolve the HTML files (in my external .jar project) using Thymeleaf I am using the following code:

```
//Here I build a specific Template Resolver (FileTemplateResolver) and add it to the 
//SpringTemplateEngine already created (by Spring Boot) with the lowest priority,
//to resolve the HTML files that are in my external project in
//resources / templates / mailTemplates / templatesPreDefined.
@PostConstruct
public void customTemplateResolver(){

    try {

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(getTemplateResolver());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        LOGGER.debug("Não foi possível definir um template resolver customizado para que seja utilizado"
                + " os templates pré definidos.", e);

    }

}

private ITemplateResolver getTemplateResolver() throws CustomTemplateResolverException {

    FileTemplateResolver resolver = new  FileTemplateResolver();

    resolver.setPrefix(getPrefixTemplateResolver());        
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    resolver.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);

    return resolver;
}

private String getPrefixTemplateResolver() throws CustomTemplateResolverException{

    try {           

        return getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath() 
                + "templates" + BARRA + "mailTemplates" + BARRA + "templatesPredefined" + BARRA;

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

        LOGGER.debug("Não foi possível obter o prefixo (classpath) do template resolver.", e);

        throw new CustomTemplateResolverException("Não foi possível obter o prefixo (classpath) do template resolver.", e);

    }

}

//In the section below is where to process the HTML files of my external project.
@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

@Autowired
private Context context;

templateEngine.process("mailTemplate", context)
```

This works very well, but in order to make the code more organized, I would not like to put all css inside the HTML, but in an external file that I will import later. But when I use the code below `th:href="@{/css/app/app.css}"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
//I need to import this app.css which is in my 
//resources/static/css/app/app.css folder in my external project.
<link id="appcss" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/app/app.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<span style="color: red; border-color: 1px solid red;" th:text="${message}">    </span>
<span class="teste">Mail Template</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

```
Link base "/css/app/app.css" cannot be context relative (/) or page relative 
unless you implement the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface 
(context is of class: org.thymeleaf.context.Context) (mailTemplate:4)
```

This my project will run as an external library to the main project, so the context and path I have is the main project. How do I set a resources folder and have thymeleaf identify the same in importing features in a project that will execute as a library (.jar)?

Note: The two projects (primary and secondary) are using Spring Boot 1.4 and consequently the aggregate version of Thymeleaf.

Comment: did you try to set `resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");`?

Comment: I already have this @DimaSan definition. I own this definition to find the HTML files within my external project (.jar). But as the classpath is the main application, I set the prefix as `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()`. This works perfectly. But I can not import a CSS that way `th:href="@ {/css/app/app.css}"` in my HTML files.